# Defining event order for @HostListener event in angular directive

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 9 app with a parent component that has contains a child-component (let's call it "overview") which contains a button. When clicking the button, the child-component emits an event that is caught in the parent component to replace the child-component with another component (let's call it "detail").

The button in the "overview"-component has a directive with a `@HostListener` to capture button clicks. My problem is that this listener is never executed because apparently, when the child component is replaced, Angular does not wait for the click listeners in the directive to be executed.

Is there a way to force Angular to execute the click listener defined with the `@HostListener` on the directive **before** the click listener defined in the component itself?

Sample code:

**Parent component**

```html
<!-- parent.component.html -->
<div>
  <overview *ngIf="currentStep == cardStep.OVERVIEW"
            (proceedToDetailView)="currentStep = cardStep.DETAIL"
  ></overview>
  <detail *ngIf="currentStep == cardStep.DETAIL"></detail>
</div>
```

```js
// parent.component.ts

export enum CardStep {
  OVERVIEW = 'OVERVIEW',
  DETAIL= 'DETAIL',
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
})
export class ParentComponent {
  currentStep = CardStep.OVERVIEW;
  cardStep = CardStep;
}
```

**Overview component**

```html
<!-- overview.component.html -->
<div>
  <button myDirective 
          (click)="proceedToDetail()"
  ></button>
</div>
```

```js
// overview.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: 'overview',
  templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
})
export class OverviewComponent{
  @Output() proceedToDetailView = new EventEmitter();

  proceedToDetail(): void {
    this.proceedToDetailView.emit();
  }
}
```

**Directive**

```js
// my.directive.ts

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective {
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  handleEvent(event): void {
    console.log('this should be executed, but isn't');
  }
}
```

Comment: a shot in the dark, and your code should probably not depend on it, but what happens if you put `myDirective` after the `(click)` listener in the template: `<button (click)="proceedToDetail()" myDirective></button>`

Comment: I tried out both, the location of the directive does not have an influence on the behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make your `@Output parameter` async, this will call the parent function on the next tick, so your directive click will be called

```
  @Output() proceedToDetailView = new EventEmitter(true); // this will change from sync to async
```

Comment: completely forgot about that feature, great answer

Comment: it's good to know your API. Your suggestion worked for me. Thanks!